# Query params in Nextjs pathname are being decoded

Tags: typescript, next.js

We're ingesting some data from an api where we're using the url to navigate through the application. In our link component we're passing a url as `<Link href={{ pathname: url , someOtherProperty }} />` where the url looks like `/path-to-page?query=value` but when I look on the client I'm seeing that the url is being returned as `/path-to-page%3Fquery=value`. The url is fine when we aren't passing an object to `href` like `<Link href={url} />`.
`decodeURIComponent` also doesn't work when passing the url into `pathname` because it's technically correct until it's rendered to the client.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am literally facing the same issue, when my href query objects contain special character values such as @ and so on, nextjs link generates a broken url on the client

Answer (score 0):

When using a URL object in the `Link`'s `href` property, the value you pass to `pathname` will be percent-encoded. If you need to pass query params you can simply use the `query` prop.

```js
<Link href={{
    pathname: '/path-to-page',
    query: { query: 'value' }
}}>
```